# How to make 5 conditional with only 1 if 2 else if 1 else?

Tags: php

I have a certain conditional like below.

```
>80 category A
71-80 category AB 
51-70 category B
41-50 category BC 
<40 category C
```

I need to make a code that meet above condition. But only with
1 if
2 else if
1 else

I figured out that i need to set the default category value, but it still does not meet the expected result

```
$category= "C";
$value = "10";

if ($value > 80) {
  $category = "A";
}else if ($value <= 70 AND $value > 50) {
  $category = "B";
}else if ($value <= 80 AND $value > 70) {
  $category = "AB";
}else{
  $category = "BC";
}

echo $category;
```

i want to make output like this

```
90 = A 
72 = AB
55 = B 
45 = BC
10 = C
```

but my code show below

```
90 = A 
72 = AB
55 = B 
45 = BC
10 = BC
```

Comment: You can't do it with 2 `elseif`.

Comment: Where does the requirement come from? Homework? Interview question? Just because?

Comment: this is code challenge from college

Comment: @MalhadiJr What is the answer for `= 40` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point is to limit the keywords `if`, `else` and `else if`, you can use ternary operator in the last else.

```
function getCat($val)
{
    $cat = '';

    if ($val >= 81) {
        $cat = 'A';
    } else if ($val >= 71 && $val <= 80) {
        $cat = 'AB';
    } else if ($val >= 51 && $val <= 70) {
        $cat = 'B';
    } else {
        $cat = $val < 40 ? 'C' : 'BC';
    }

    return $cat;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/EuFvD)

There's one issue though. If the value is `40`, this would give it `BC`, but you never wrote any rule for that number so it is what it is

Comment: Thanks, i think this is an alternative solution for the challenge. But i wonder if there is a solution using an array to store the category.

Comment: this is an alternative answer from my friend, he write the code with C++

https://scontent-sin6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/70325118_912806349100201_7879901134180057088_n.png?_nc_cat=103&_nc_oc=AQkeURyrSNkyozGrTc9LRnTn8IZELB0ykxeZ7Xd9rD2q3S9mFJ0CLZVHzrSkgDPno_k&_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-1.xx&oh=5b9455af05c4770f854c9645f05f9bc7&oe=5DF03B6F

Comment: in that code, he divide the value with 50. then assign the result to an array to get the category.

Comment: @MalhadiJr that's the answer. Division on a limited range gives you only 2 options of `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like this:

```
<?php

$value = 81;
$edge_cases = ['C','A'];

$category = '';

if($value > 40 && $value <= 50){
    $category = 'BC';
}else if($value > 50 && $value <= 70){
    $category = 'B';
}else if($value > 70 && $value <= 80){
    $category = 'AB';
}else{
    $quotient = intval($value / 80);
    $index = abs(intval($quotient / (($quotient - 1) | 1)));
    $category = $edge_cases[$index];
}

echo $category;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/78S4p

Although it's always better to make division between a range and get the quotient as only 2 options of either `0` or `1`, here is another way of doing the same thing.

In the above code, we make sure that we always get the index as `1` if `$quotient > 0`, else we make it `0` itself.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, only one if statement is used and you said that you would like an array solution in one of the comments:

```
$categories = [
   '80' => 'A',
   '71' => 'AB',
   '51' => 'B',
   '41' => 'BC',
];

$value = "10";
$category= "C";
foreach ($categories as $minVal => $cat) {
  if ($value >= $minVal) {
     $category = $cat;
     break;
  }
}

echo $category;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
if ($value < 40 ) {
    $category = "C";
}else if ($value <= 50 && $value != 40) {
    $category = "BC";
}else if ($value <= 70 ) {
    $category = "B";
}else{
    $category = $value > 80 ? "A" : "AB";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use a ternary you can do this :

```
if ($value > 80) {
    $category = 'A';
} else if ($value > 70) {
    $category = 'AB';
} else if ($value > 50) {
    $category = 'B';
} else {
    $category = $value > 40 ? 'BC' : 'C';
}
```

@u_mulder thought the same ^^

Comment: With such approach we can even reduce to `if else`)))

Comment: this is an alternative answer from my friend, he write the code with C++

https://scontent-sin6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/70325118_912806349100201_7879901134180057088_n.png?_nc_cat=103&_nc_oc=AQkeURyrSNkyozGrTc9LRnTn8IZELB0ykxeZ7Xd9rD2q3S9mFJ0CLZVHzrSkgDPno_k&_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-1.xx&oh=5b9455af05c4770f854c9645f05f9bc7&oe=5DF03B6F

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I think I completely missed the point, but I thought I would answer more for entertainment and as a complete alternative to the problem.  I present the no if solution...

```
$category = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'BC', 'B', 'B', 'AB', 'A', 'A' ];

echo $category[min(max(floor(($value-1)/10),0),9)];
```

I ended up adding the `min()` and `max()` to ensure it didn't get errors with -1 or 101.

If people think my answer should be deleted, then let me know as I am not answering the original problem :-/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that should satisfy the conditions. The `else` obviously isn't really necessary.

```
$category = '';
if ($value > 70 && !($category .= 'A')) {
} elseif ($value > 40 && $value < 81 && !($category .='B')) {
} elseif ($value < 51 && $category .= 'C') {
} else {}
```